# how can i get the value of another variable in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write some code in C# with unity where i have an object who's position I need to know for my script to work. I was trying to use a pointer as that's what I thought was used. It said i had to use an unsafe tag which made me think i was doing something wrong. I am a little new to this and so far i have most of my knowledge with C++ as that's what i have learned in class. I tried looking it up but i could not find it. this is basically what i have right now.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SGravSim : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject moon;
public GameObject earth;

private struct Cords
{
    public float* x
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != 0) <== this thing is realy just a placeholder
                x = value;
        }
    }
    public float* y
    {
        get
        {
            return y;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != 0) <== this this is only in here for now 
                y = value;
        }
    }
    public void DisplayX()
    {

    }
}
private Cords moonLocation;
private Cords earthLocation;
private Cords SataliteLocation;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    moonLocation.x = moon.transform.position.x;        
    moonLocation.y = moon.transform.position.y;
    earthLocation.x = earth.transform.position.x;
    earthLocation.y = earth.transform.position.y;
    SataliteLocation.x = this.transform.position.x;
    SataliteLocation.y = this.transform.position.y;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Debug.Log(moon.transform.position.x);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The position of the transform in world space.

    float yMoon = moon.transform.position.x
    print(moonLocation.y);

}
}
```

I was planing on making the set so that you could not add anything to it.
I guess I could write out the whole earth.position.x thing every time I need to use it I was just trying to see if there was a better way to do it and also a way where I cant mess with the variable as all I want to do is read it.

Comment: I really couldn't figure out your problem here. but here is a few things I noticed: 1- you should use class not struct if you need to use reference instead of value. so no need for pointers. 2- if you don't want setter don't define it, you can just modify the default constructor to accept the values.

Comment: Why don't you simply leave out the `set`s if you just need read access via `get`?

Comment: Please explain what you want to solve, the question is very unclear as it stands now as it asks a hard to comprehend question about a potential solution to an unknown problem. Ask about that problem instead, what is the overarching problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use pointers in c# except for really specific cases. 
The solution several people gave you here is good:

```
public float X {get; private set;}
```

It is called a property and is one of the nice possibilities in c# to avoid creating getters and setters.

You say you have some knowledge in c++, but c# is actually closer to higher languages such as java. You should focus on the Object Oriented way to code and forget about low level pointers, especially using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use private set in the automatic properties :

```
 public float X {get; private set;}
```

This way only your class will be able to set the variable but any other class wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
private float x;
public float X
{
    get
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Now you only set x from within your class.

Answer (score 0):

You get the unsafe tag warning, because you try to use pointers, which are actually unsafe. There might be use-cases for that, but in C# you generally use [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) and value types. In C# a struct is a value type, so it will behave differently compared to a reference type, as you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx), which is also why Gubr has suggested to use a class instead of a struct. Last but not least, there is a difference in how they are stored, just google C# heap and stack.

I haven't used structs that much in C# yet, so I just created a new project and played a bit around.

So I used your code, which also could just look like this:

```
private struct Cords
    {
        public float x, y;
        public void DisplayX(){}
    }
```

As the others have mentioned, you could leave out the set or make it private and add a constructor. Mind you, a private set doesn't equal to not defining it in auto-properties. Instead, it will create a readonly field. However, you have to call the new operator in both cases to set the value:

```
private struct Cords
    {
        public float X { get; }

        public float Y { get; }

        public void DisplayX(){}

        public Cords(float x, float y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
```

And here we create a new Cords:

```
Cords earth = new Cords(10.005f, 12.689f);
```